# Вывод данных по циклу

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток, есть таблица auto там уровень имя машины скорость и тд, мне нужно вывести автомобили которые доступны на моем уровне тоесть если мой ур 2 вывести все машины 2 ур. причем выводя имашины остальных ур .. если не поняля объясню  ..

Comment: непонятно и много опечаток, сделайте ваши таблицы здесь:

http://sqlfiddle.com/

----

а так-же

@anonymous_911_, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д. покажите что вы уже пробовали и в чем проблема. это не форум бесплатных кодеров.

Comment: @anonymous_911_, именно я и "*не поняля*". Даже интересно стало, каким же будет объяснение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Интересно я угадал?
**1 Вариант:**

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM auto WHERE level >= ".$my_level);
```

**2 Вариант**

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM auto WHERE level = ".$my_level);
```

**3 Вариант**

```
$a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM auto WHERE level = ".$my_level);
$b = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM auto);
```

Где level - столбец отвечающий у вас за уровень;
    auto - таблица которая содержит машины;
    $my_level - переменная с вашим уровнем.

Comment: ЭТО Я ЗНАЮ, НО ВЦИКЛЕ КАК ВЫВЕСТИ Я ВОТ ВЫВОЖУ ВЦЫКЛЕ ВСЕ МАШИНЫ КОТОРЫЕ ДОСТУПНЫ НА МОЕМ УРОВНЕ, НО КОГДА НА НОВЫЙ УР ПЕРЕХОЖУ ВЫВОДЯТЬСЯ МАШИНЫ НОВОГО УРОВНЯ, НО МАШИНЫ 1 УРОВНЯ ИСЧЕЗАЮТ, ПОНЯТНО ???

Comment: Хотя вы угодали первый вариант правельный